# Add columns to back4app table on Android studio from a different page after already creating row

Tags: android, android-studio, back4app

Creating an app on Android studio, have a registration page working which updates the User table on back4app - it also creates a session table with sessionID associated with the account. I'm trying to make it so once the username and password have been confirmed and added the user is brought to a new page and more details are further taken and added to the row in the same User table.
My code for the section looks like

```
private void addPersonalDetailsToDatabase(String firstname,
                                              String lastname,
                                              String dob,
                                              String addressline1,
                                              String addressline2,
                                              String postcode,
                                              String livealone,
                                              String havecarers) {

        ParseObject userList = new ParseObject("User");

        userList.put("firstname", firstname);
        userList.put("lastname", lastname);
        userList.put("dob", dob);
        userList.put("addressline1", addressline1);
        userList.put("addressline2", addressline2);
        userList.put("postcode", postcode);
        userList.put("livealone", livealone);
        userList.put("havecarers", havecarers);

        userList.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(PersonalDetailsForm.this, "Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    openPDConfirmed();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        });
    }
```

However when I run this code and enter the details it creates a new User table with a brand new row which isn't then accessed by the sessionID.

What I'm trying to do is to add these new columns and their contents to the original user table for the user that has just logged in. Is there any errors in my code or any way that I could add new columns to an already existing row.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Updated it there - hopefully thats a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

Try `ParseObject userList = new ParseObject("_User");` or `ParseUser userList = new ParseUser();`